# MS Access trying to link a record with a page tab

Tags: performance, ms-access, tabs, records

I've been searching for a few days and doing every word combination I can think of to try to find the answer to my issue. I'm hoping someone can help me.

Before I begin I'd also like to say I'm very new to Access and admittedly not great with it. I'm still learning so this could be a very easy fix or I may have messed up beyond belief.

The issue I'm having is I've setup several page tab on a form and entered all the information for my records. However I cannot get the page tabs to pull up the corresponding records. Instead I have to either search through the records which doesn't always work or I have to arrow to the right record after selecting the tab I want. I'd like it so that when I click the tab it brings up the proper record automatically. If someone can point out where I'm going wrong and how to fix it I would greatly appreciate it. See below for some pics of what I mean.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the first image. The tab name "Auto PLUS" doesn't bring up the proper record. instead I have to manually change the record using the arrows at the bottom of the form (see the arrow at the bottom of the image) in order to change the record. I need the record and the tab to match. Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help!!
-Deke

Comment: We're going to need to know a bit more about what the "proper record" means.

Comment: By proper record I mean the information stored in my TBLOutagetype under tables. Here is an image of what I mean...                                    ![valid XHTML][checkmark]. Sorry can't seem to get my picture uploaded... but basically the table is setup with 4 columns. ID, Affected, Instructions, and Special Notes. Then the rows are ID Numbered 1 -17 with each row having the information filled it. Each tab I have should reflect one of these rows.
 
[checkmark]: C:\users\def014\desktop\untitled3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your form is bound (if in design mode your fields do NOT say "Unbound" then your form is bound), you simply need to add some VBA code to each tab's `OnClick` event.

Enter design mode and select the first tab "Claims Other". Open the properties pane, click the event tab, and click the ellipsis at the end of the `OnClick` line. When prompted, select "Code Builder" and it should launch the Visual Basic Editor.

It will put your cursor automatically in the correct position. Copy/Paste:

`DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Form1, acGoTo, 1`

**The `1` should correspond to "Claims Other's" proper record in your table. Use the row number, not the ID number to determine what it should be.**

Go back to Form View and click on the "Claims Other's" tab. The data should show the corresponding record in your table.

Repeat the steps of adding events to each tab, finding the relevant record in your table, and replacing the `1` from the above code.

Comment: @Deke sorry for the edits, this is probably the simplest way to get it to work properly.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was thinking this was how I was supposed to get it to work but since I'm not good with coding I had no idea how to start. I am having a bit of a problem though. I've cut and pasted the code but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong but I have been doing what you said and using the row number rather than the ID. I'm gonna keep messing with it but if I can't get it to work I'll post again and hopefully be able to put up some pictures to show what's happening. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Okay So what I've found is I'm getting the following error. " this action requires an object name argument." run-time 2493 Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I figured out the problem and got it to work I used the following code in order to get it to work, incase anyone needs this in the future. [Code] DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Form1", acGoTo, 2 [/Code] hope it helps! thanks again for your help Chris!!!!

Comment: Sorry about that Deke, I should have checked the syntax. Looks like I missed the acGoTo argument, glad I could help though!